# Mac Mini with projection TV always needs underscan adjustment

Tags: mac, display

I have a late 2014 Mac Mini, A1347 and it's hooked up to my home entertainment center. The video goes through an HDMI cable to an HDMI switcher, then to a projection TV. Every time I reboot the top and bottom of the Mac screen is cut off. I have to open Preferences, go to Display and, as soon as I touch the Underscan adjustment with the mouse, the image immediately resizes to where it needs to be. If I don't do this, it never resizes so I can see the top (including the menubar) or the bottom (most of the dock).

What can I do to have the needed settings come up at boot?

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem with an old Mac Mini and a Samsung TV display. On googling the issue I found an AppleScript solution at:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68788660/mac-underscan-adjusment-coding-problem-applescript

which looks quite promising but haven't had the chance to try it out in practice yet.

If I get it working I'll report back, with hardware & software config details.

in friendship

Rowland